# Magento 1.9 - To get all simple(associated) products of grouped product regardless of websites/store views

Tags: magento-1.9, grouped-products

I'm operating multiple websites(storeviews) and i want to bring all simple products on A website although it doesn't be checked to appear on  `A` website on product-website tab.

There would be only grouped products on A website and then click them, i want to show all of simple products associated with the grouped product even they are not a member of `A` website.

Literally, I'd like to implement what shows in Magento Admin Page on A website catalog page.

So, I want to modify grouped.phtml file and it needs that a product(grouped product) that this module calls have to call all of associated simple product regardless of checking this website or not. Is there a way to implement this ? Please share your opinion.

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/Grouped.phtml

```
<?php $this->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $this->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable() && $_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

## **EDIT**

> /wh-clone/app/code/local/Kbethos/AllProducts/Block/Product/View/Type/Grouped.php

```
<?php
class Kbethos_AllProducts_Block_Product_View_Type_Grouped extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Revert getProduct functionality to parent:parent
     * 
     * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
     * @return null|Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
     */
    /*
    public function getProduct()
    {
    if (!$this->hasData('product')) {
        $this->setData('product', Mage::registry('product'));
    }

    return $this->getData('product');
    }
    */

}
```

> app/code/local/Kbethos/AllProducts/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Kbethos_AllProducts>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Kbethos_AllProducts>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
        <allproducts>
            <class>Kbethos_AllProducts_Block</class>
        </allproducts>  
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
      <allproducts>
        <class>Kbethos_AllProducts_Helper</class>
      </allproducts>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

> app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/catalog.xml

```
<!-- 20170608 mj edit - add new block for grouped -->
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Grouped)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="kbethos/allproducts_block" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped> 
 <!-- 20170608 mj edit - add new block for grouped -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

If you take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Abstract::getProduct` (`/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Abstract.php`) you can see that the block retrieves the product with a store filter applied to it.

You will need to create a custom module that overrides this function, calling the product without the store filter.

Take a look at http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/ for information regarding how to override blocks (and other classes).

To get you started `/app/code/local/MyModule/Grouped/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_Grouped>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyModule_Grouped>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_type_grouped>MyModule_Grouped_Block_Rewrite_Product_View_Type_Grouped</product_view_type_grouped>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

`/app/code/local/MyModule/Grouped/Block/Rewrite/Product/View/Type/Grouped.php`

```
class MyModule_Grouped_Block_Rewrite_Product_View_Type_Grouped extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Grouped
{
    /**
     * Revert getProduct functionality to parent:parent
     * 
     * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
     * @return null|Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('product')) {
            $this->setData('product', Mage::registry('product'));
        }

        return $this->getData('product');
    }
}
```

You'll need to flesh out the module a little more, but hopefully that helps. The block override essentially calls the parent class' parent method (reverting to the default `getProduct` functionality)

This is untested!

A better way of doing this would be to create your own module that does exactly what you want without overwriting anything!

**Method 2**

Instead of overriding the functionality in the block class you could create a new block that extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` rather than `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Abstract` and simply leave the class empty. As you've extended from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` the `getProduct` functionality will not assign a store to a product.

Then update the `PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable` node block in your themes layout XML to use your new block that doesn't use any of the store assigning functionality. Eg: `mymodule/my_new_grouped_block`

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Grouped)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="mymodule/my_new_grouped_block" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

Comment: Thank you! Btw is there a way to adapt this code(or function) for a specific website? I mean if i modify this core one or overwriting it,  it would affects other websites bc we have multiple websites under one magento installation. They are using different themes so i'm looking for how to bring all simple products on design file.

Comment: See my "Method 2" for that sort of functionality. Basically you'd have to create a custom module in the same way but not rewrite a Magento core file, instead create a custom block, then in your theme specific layout XML files you can set which block you want to display on which site.

Just so you know, never modify core files! Always create a module that extends/rewrites them!

Comment: Please see my edit codes?

Comment: I edit code as i posted. But it doesn't work :/ Please can you have a look my code?

Comment: Hey! your idea was so interesting but i modified core code just a moment and recovered it. It doesn't work. I mean even though i changed `getProduct()` which brings products filtered by stores with `getProduct()` which brings products from registry, this block i costumed doesn't work!

Comment: I'll take a look at your code later today, in work at the moment!